# Find the Gaussian probability density of x for a normal distribution

Tags: python, gaussian, normal-distribution

So, I'm supposed to write a function `normpdf(x , avg, std)` that returns the Gaussian probability density function of `x` for a normal distribution with mean `avg` and standard deviation `std`, with `avg = 0` and `std = 1`.

This is what I got so far, but when I click run, I get this message:

```py
Input In [95]
    return pdf
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm confused on what I did wrong on that part.

```py
import numpy as np
import math


def normpdf(x, avg=0, std=1) : 
    # normal distribution eq
    exponent = math.exp(-0.5 * ((x - avg) / std) ** 2)
    pdf = (1 / (std * math.sqrt(2 * math.pi)) * exponent)
    return pdf

# set x values 
x = np.linspace(1, 50)

normpdf(x, avg, std)
```

I added the parenthesis here and `math.sqrt`:

```py
pdf = (1 / (std * math.sqrt(2 * math.pi)) * exponent)
```

... but then I got this message:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [114], in <cell line: 11>()
      9     pdf = (1/(std*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))*exponent)
     10     return pdf
---> 11 normpdf(x, avg, std)

Input In [114], in normpdf(x, avg, std)
      6 def normpdf(x, avg=0, std=1) : 
      7     #normal distribution eq
----> 8     exponent = math.exp(-0.5*((x-avg)/std)**2)
      9     pdf = (1/(std*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))*exponent)
     10     return pdf

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: You did not close the bracket in the pdf line:
`pdf = (1/(std*sqrt(2*math.pi))*exponent` . This should possibly read: `pdf = (1/(std*sqrt(2*math.pi))*exponent)`. You might want to consider using a code editor (e.g. VS Code with Python extension) to spot such mistakes.

Comment: By the way, you will also need to define `sqrt`. You could import it from the `math` library. See also here for reference: https://realpython.com/python-square-root-function/.

Comment: Your function isn't vectorized so you can't pass it an array like `x`. Maybe try using `np.sqrt` and `np.exp`.

Comment: Or do something like: y = [normpdf(a) for a in x]

Comment: If `avg` and `std` are always going to be `0` and `1`, respectively, then `((x - avg) / std)` doesn't make any sense. That will always be `x`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `math` module. Use just `numpy` functions:

```py
import numpy as np


def normpdf(x, avg=0, std=1):
    exp = np.exp(-0.5 * ((x - avg) / std) ** 2)
    pdf = (1 / (std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * exp)
    return pdf


x = np.linspace(1, 50)

print(normpdf(x))
```

The code above will result in:

```py
[2.41970725e-001 5.39909665e-002 4.43184841e-003 1.33830226e-004
 1.48671951e-006 6.07588285e-009 9.13472041e-012 5.05227108e-015
 1.02797736e-018 7.69459863e-023 2.11881925e-027 2.14638374e-032
 7.99882776e-038 1.09660656e-043 5.53070955e-050 1.02616307e-056
 7.00418213e-064 1.75874954e-071 1.62463604e-079 5.52094836e-088
 6.90202942e-097 3.17428155e-106 5.37056037e-116 3.34271444e-126
 7.65392974e-137 6.44725997e-148 1.99788926e-159 2.27757748e-171
 9.55169454e-184 1.47364613e-196 8.36395161e-210 1.74636626e-223
 1.34141967e-237 3.79052640e-252 3.94039628e-267 1.50690472e-282
 2.12000655e-298 1.09722105e-314 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
```